# Get button content in event

Tags: c#, xaml

I have the code in `XAML`:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnSete" Click="btn_Click">
    <ContentControl.Content>
        <Viewbox Margin="3">
            <TextBlock Text="7"/>
        </Viewbox>
     </ContentControl.Content>
</Button>
```

And code behind:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Button btn = (Button)e.Source;

   txbDisplay.Text = btn.Content.ToString();
}
```

how do I get the value of `<TextBlock Text="7"/>` in `btn_Click`?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11405038/2907017

Comment: possible duplicate of [get clicked button content from button styled listbox binded to xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404918/get-clicked-button-content-from-button-styled-listbox-binded-to-xml)

Comment: Though, while I think this question is a duplicate if you really want to retrieve the *content* of the button, in this case (with the value you are looking for being constant), the clean way to do things would probably be to simply subclass `Button` and provide it with an additional property that allows you to distinguish your buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your XAML, `btn.Content` should be the instance of the `Viewbox`. Then the `Child` property of the `Viewbox` should be your `TextBlock`.

So you should be able to do this (inside your button click event handler):

```
var viewBox = (Viewbox)btn.Content;
var textBlock = (TextBlock)viewBox.Child;
var text = textBlock.Text; //  This is the value you were looking for

txbDisplay.Text = text;
```

Also, just as a helpful note, the `<ContentControl.Content> ... </ContentControl.Content>` part of your XAML is superfluous. That block could just be written as:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnSete" Click="btn_Click">
    <Viewbox Margin="3">
        <TextBlock Text="7"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

See the "XAML Content Properties" section on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information why that is if you're not sure.